# Gnome DE brightness setting is not remembered after screen lock

Tags: gnome, brightness

I am using Rocky Linux 8.x workstation with Gnome DE for a couple of years now with no problems.

About a week ago the following issue comes up:

If I lock the screen using eg the Super(Win) key-L, and then I log back in, the screen brightness is at maximum. And I need to manually lower the brightness each time. It seems the brightness setting is no longer remembered during a lock screen.

Any help is much appreciated.